# Join three SQL Server CTEs

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression, stored-functions

I've been working on this for a little while now, and I think I'm close to finishing. I've managed to find a way using CTE a and b and an inner join, to merge my two results. I'm looking for a possible way to add my running average column (c)  to this result as well. But nothing I try seems to work. Any guidance on how I'm supposed to go about doing this or a more ideal way to handle this would be appreciated.

Image:

[image]

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_rptAppointmentsBreakdown2]
    (@startDate DATETIME, 
     @endDate DATETIME) 
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
    RETURN 
        (WITH a AS
         (
             SELECT 
                 calendar_date,
                 SUM(cIsFS + cIsGB + cIsCH+ cIsGC + cIsWM + cIsTC + cIsAR + cIsPP + cIsC3 + cIsPW) AS 'TotalBookedPRU', 
                 SUM(cShowedUp * cIsFS) + SUM(cShowedUp * cIsCH) +
                     SUM(cShowedUp * cIsPW) AS Showed,
                 NULL AS 'Total Booked',
                 SUM(cIsNoShow * cIsC3) + SUM(cIsNoShow * cIsPW) AS 'No Shows/ Rebooked'
             FROM 
                 reports.dbo.vw_Appointments a
             WHERE
                 cAppointmentType = 'Recalls' AND
                 CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), calendar_date, 112)) BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate 
             GROUP BY 
                 calendar_date
         ),
         b AS
         (
             SELECT 
                 calendar_date,
                 NULL AS 'Total Booked pru',    
                 NULL AS Showed,
                 SUM(cIsFS + cIsGB + cIsCH+ cIsGC + cIsWM + cIsTC + cIsAR + cIsPP + cIsC3 + cIsPW) AS 'TotalBooked',    
                 NULL AS 'No Shows/ Rebooked'
             FROM 
                 reports.dbo.vw_Appointments a
             WHERE
                 CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), calendar_date, 112)) BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate 
             GROUP BY 
                 calendar_date
        ),
        c AS 
        (
             SELECT 
                 a.*, a2.Running_Average AS runningaverage
             FROM
                 a 
             OUTER APPLY
                 (SELECT AVG(showed) AS Running_Average
                  FROM a a2
                  WHERE a2.calendar_date <= a.calendar_date) a2
        )
        SELECT 
            a.calendar_date,
            a.TotalBookedPRU,
            a.Showed,
            b.TotalBooked
        FROM 
            a 
        INNER JOIN 
            b ON a.calendar_date = b.calendar_date
    )
```

Comment: @Larnu - Not in 2008. The `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` etc was introduced in SQL Server 2012

Comment: Just one reason of many on why to upgrade @MartinSmith. (Plus the fact it is about to run out of supported entirely). It does actually surprise me how many are still using something so close to end of life.

Answer (score 0):

Your have three cte such as `a`, `b` and `c`.

- cte `c` is not used in your pasted code of function. So it is better to remove unused code to have code clearer and easier to understand
- as at the bottom `SELECT` you are choosing just four fields such as `calendar_date, TotalBookedPRU, Showed, TotalBooked` so we can choose just fields which are in the `SELECT statement`
- added a column which calculates time `RunningTime`

  ```
  ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_rptAppointmentsBreakdown2](@startDate datetime
  , @endDate datetime) RETURNS TABLE AS
  RETURNS TABLE 
  AS
  RETURN
  (
  with a as (
     SELECT 
     calendar_date,
     SUM(cIsFS + cIsGB + cIsCH+ cIsGC + cIsWM + cIsTC + cIsAR + cIsPP + cIsC3 + cIsPW) 
         AS 'TotalBookedPRU',     
     Null AS 'Total Booked'   
     FROM reports.dbo.vw_Appointments ACTION
     WHERE
     cAppointmentType = 'Recalls' AND
     CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(8),calendar_date,112)) 
         BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate    
     GROUP BY 
     calendar_date
     ),
  b as (
      SELECT 
      calendar_date,
      null AS 'Total Booked pru', 
      null AS Showed,
      SUM(cIsFS + cIsGB + cIsCH+ cIsGC + cIsWM + cIsTC + cIsAR + cIsPP + cIsC3 
          + cIsPW) AS 'TotalBooked'   
      FROM reports.dbo.vw_Appointments a
      WHERE   CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(8),calendar_date,112)) 
          BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate    
      GROUP BY 
      calendar_date
  )

  declare @start datetime = getutcdate();  

  SELECT 
  a.calendar_date,
  a.TotalBookedPRU,
  a.Showed,
  b.TotalBooked
  , DATEDIFF(ms, @start, getutcdate()) RunningTime
  FROM a Inner join b ON a.calendar_date = b.calendar_date
  )
  ```

In addition, if you want to get how many time it is necessary to execute your query and count of input/output/reading operations of hard drive, you can use:

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
SET STATISTICS IO ON 
GO
SELECT * FROM fn_rptAppointmentsBreakdown2(/*your parameters here*/)
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
SET STATISTICS IO OFF
```